# how to automatically showing its designated form (adminform and userform) depending on user-type in .NET?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a login form where the user types his/her credentials in the txtUsername and txtPass it will automatically select from the table where users and admins are registered. it will show its designated form (adminform) and (userform) when the user typed his/her credentials depending of his/her USER-TYPE in the table. I used SQL SERVER 2012 for my database and a boolean. Do i need a boolean in this? I set a boolean and how do you make it true?

Ignore the metromessagebox its just the metroframework.

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim choice As Boolean
    con.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ConString
    cmd.Connection = con
    If txtUser.Text = "" Or txtPass.Text = "" Then
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Invalid Login", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        txtUser.Clear()
        txtPass.Clear()
        txtUser.Focus()
    ElseIf choice = True Then
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Password from UserTable where Name = '" & txtUser.Text & "' and Password = '" & txtPass.Text & "' and [User Type]='User'"

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows Then
                UserMain.Show()
                UserMain.lblName.Text = txtUser.Text
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    ElseIf choice = False Then
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Password from UserTable where Name = '" & txtUser.Text & "' and Password = '" & txtPass.Text & "' and [User Type]='Admin'"

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows Then
                AdminMain.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    Else
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Invalid Login", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify your question

Comment: I already changed my question

Comment: A quick look at the code reveals two vulnerabilities. You're concatenating user input into the query, which leads to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and also you're comparing the user provided password with the DB directly, revealing that you're storing it in plain text. Use [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) at least.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `boolean` you mention, is that the `choice`? You have declare it but didn't assign any value, so the default is `false`.  And you may want to get the "User Type" from your table, and check the value, so "No record -> user not exists", "Return record -> either Admin or User"

Comment: I guess the DB should store the user type, and after authenticating the user you can determine the right screen from there.

Comment: My table has a column `[User Type]` which selects from the query.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Alejandro you are prone to SQL injection and also storing password as a plain text is a bad practice. However answering your question, checking on returned value of [User Type] will do.

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim choice As Boolean
con.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ConString
cmd.Connection = con
If txtUser.Text = "" Or txtPass.Text = "" Then
    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Invalid Login", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    txtUser.Clear()
    txtPass.Clear()
    txtUser.Focus()
Else
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Password, [User Type] from UserTable where Name = '" & txtUser.Text & "' and Password = '" & txtPass.Text & "'"

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
    if dr.item("User Type") = "Admin" Then
            AdminMain.Show()
                Me.Hide()
    Else
        UserMain.Show()
                UserMain.lblName.Text = txtUser.Text
                Me.Hide()   
    End If
    Else
    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Invalid Login", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
Catch myerror As SqlException
    MessageBox.Show("An error Occurred: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And also Importing Metroframework will remove using of MetroFramework word

```
MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Invalid Login", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
```

Hope this helps!